# What does the draft mode change?

Tags: packages, document-classes, big-list, draft

I wonder which changes are made by the `draft` option?

That means what will be changed by calling it as global class option (`\documentclass[draft]{<class>}`) or locally for a single package if it is available (`\usepackage[draft]){<package>}`.

---

**Note**
I know that this depends on the loaded packages and if they react on the `draft` option or not. But I thought it could be helpful to have a overview which packages do what.

I suggest the answers to be **CW** and using this layout

```
Package/Class: `name`  
Changes

- one
- two

Has `final` option too: yes/no
```

If you like we can discuss the layout in meta …

Comment: While I like your question, I don't see a point in adding several CW answers. Why not write a single answer covering everything you know (with appropriate sections) and let other users add their knowledge either in separate answers (provided your answer was non-CW) or by editing your (CW) answer?

Comment: @lockstep: Hm … I though it’s a little more tidy in separate answers. And furthermore the answers can be sorted by importance/relevance by upvoting them. If you comment get’s 5 upvotes (do we call it upvotes for comments too?) I’ll merge the CW answers.

Comment: Several packages for setting someting in the page background, e.g `draftmark` or `xwatermark`, have a `draft` and `final` option, but I was too lazy to search for, what it means in each case.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: The question shouldn’t explain it. For that we have the answers below. And since it depends on the packages one can’t say what the option does in general ;-)

Comment: @lockstep: I decided to make an overview answer and keeping the more detailed single answers. I guess thats a good compromise, isn’t it? I’ll stick the overview to the top by accepting as soon as it is possible to accept my own answer.

Comment: @Tobi a) It's at least better than the current situation ;-) b) Self-accepted answers don't flow to the top automatically -- they have to have the highest score, too.

Comment: @lockstep: b) OK, than I’ll hope that it get’s the highest votes … Since it’s CW it won’t influence my reputation if we upvote it to make it the top answer …

Comment: @lockstep: b) woud’t it be possible that you copy my overview answer in a new CW answer. Then it should be sticked to the top even if it’s not the one with the highest votes …?

Comment: @Tobi: I didn't mean you should say what it _does_, but what it _is_ (as in, an option to `\documentclass` which can (sometimes?) also be set and/or overridden on a per-package basis). Of course, maybe that really belongs in the [tag:draft] tag wiki; I'd write it if I actually had a clue what to write there.

Comment: Explaining the `draft` option to a document class and `draftmode` to `latex` or `pdflatex` may be interesting as well.

Comment: @DamienWalters: I think that the `draft` (class) option and `(pdf)latex`’s `-draftmode` are too different to be covered in the same question. I suggest you ask “What does `-draftmode` do?” or something like that and we can link both questions.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

## Overview

<sub>Please add your answer here in alphabetical order too</sub>

### Classes

Print a box at the end of overfull lines.
See [this answer below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49278/4918) for a list of classes and details.

### Packages

<sub>The links lead to the answers below.</sub>

- [`changes`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156746) (`final` disables markup of changes, and list of changes)
- [`cryptocode`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cryptocode) (disables syntax highlighting to reduce compilation time)
- [`flowfram`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/331446) (show frame, typeblock and margin bounding boxes)
- [`graphics`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49283) (draw frames instead of including images)
- [`graphicx`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49283) (draw frames instead of including images)
- [`hyperref`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49340) (disable all linking features)
- [`listings`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49284) (don’t include external files)
- [`listofsymbols`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49303) (`final` suppresses printing of macro names and unused symbols)
- [`mfpic`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49302) (assume every `latex` run to be the first one)
- [`pdfcomment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49342) (`final` suppresses the comments)
- [`pdfpages`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49288) (don’t include external file but print a frame box)
- [`pgf`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49410) (similar to `graphics/x`: all images will be replaced by empty rectangles)
- [`pstricks`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/583444) (no native support, but a workaround)
- [`showkeys`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49287) (`draft` shows the labels, the default option)
- [`showlabels`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/showlabels) (`draft` shows the labels, the [default option](http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/showlabels/showlabels.pdf))
- [`thumbs`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49412) (thumbs' width=2pt, thumbs' text=black, thumbs' color=grey)
- [`todonotes`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/todonotes) (with `obeyDraft` package only enabled in draft mode)
- [`varioref`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49289) (turn warnings in error messages)

### Related questions:

- The tag: **[draft](/questions/tagged/draft)** (click to see questions tagged)
- [Doing something only when the draft option is on?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21234)
- [Disabling the draft option in a package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33245)
- [Changing implementation of 'draft' option](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13426)
- Not directly related but maybe interesting in this context too: [How to speed up LaTeX compilation with several TikZ pictures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45)

Answer (score 21):

Package: `microtype`

- The `draft` option no longer exists, but can be emulated by loading the package with `disable=ifdraft`:

  > If the `disable` option is passed to the package, all micro-typographic extensions will be disabled, which may lead to different line, and hence even page, breaks. This option replaces the `draft` option from earlier versions, which could be inherited from the class options; to restore the previous behaviour, you may pass the value `ifdraft`: in this case, the `disable` option will be set to true if and only if the document class has been loaded with the `draft` option.

Has `final` option: no

Answer (score 13):

## Document classes

Standard: `article`, `book`, `report`
AMS: `amsart`, `amsbook`, `amsproc`
KOMA-Script: `scrartcl`, `scrbook`, `scrreprt`, `scrlttr2`
Other: `proc`, `memoir`

Changes:

- Print a mark for overfull lines

  [image: overfull rule]

Have `final` option too: yes

### Related questions:

- [Can I have the \overfullrule rule colored in pdfLaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28294/4918)
- [\underfullrule?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4086/4918)
- [Suppress black box at end of line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22556/4918)

Answer (score 11):

Package: `graphicx`
Changes

- Prints frames containing the file name instead of including the images

  [image: draft] [image: final]

Has `final` option too: yes

Comment: While it wasn't asked for directly, I think the `demo` option should also be mention where you don't need the actual figure and you get a black box.

Answer (score 9):

Package: `showkeys`

- `draft` is the default setting

Has `final` option: yes, it disables all package functionality.

Answer (score 8):

Package: `varioref`
Changes:

- Turn error messages into warnings.

Has `final` option: yes

Answer (score 7):

Package: `hyperref`

Changes:

- Turns all hypertext options off

`final` option: yes

Answer (score 6):

Package: `listings`
Changes

- Doesn’t include external file but prints their caption and makes their labels.

  [image: draft]

  [image: final]

Has `final` option too: yes

Comment: How can I suppress this behaviour, or have it render a box of the SAME size as the listing, so that my DRAFT documents layout isn't heavily modified when the input listings disappear...

Comment: You can pass the `final` option directly to a package, while the `draft` class option stays active for the class and other packages without the explicit option. I.e. `\documentclass[draft]{article} ... \usepackage[final]{listings} ...`

Comment: My experience is that `draft` mode even inhibits the display of regular `lstlisting` environment listings; i.e., not only code from external files.

Answer (score 5):

Package: `pdfcomment`

- Option `draft` is the default.

Changes with `final` option:

> “PDF annotations will not be typeset and will not inﬂuence line breaking.”

(In other words: The lines will change, if inline annotations have been used.)

Answer (score 4):

Package: `listofsymbols`
Changes:

- Option `draft` is default with this package.
- Option `final` removes the macronames from the lists. Symbols that are not used
  in the document are omitted from the List of Symbols and from the
  List of Subscripts.

Has `final` option too: yes (see above)

Answer (score 3):

Package: `pdfpages`
Changes

- Does not insert pages, but prints a box and the filename instead.

Has `final` option too: yes

Comment: That behaviour is probably inherited from `graphicx`.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Yes, probably. Maybe merge the answers for these two?

Answer (score 3):

Package `pgf` *(but **not*** `TikZ`*)*

Changes:

- All images will be replaced by empty rectangles.

`final` option: yes

Answer (score 2):

Package: `mfpic`
Changes:

- Treats any `pdflatex` run as the first run, pretending figure files have not been created.

Has `final` option too: yes

Answer (score 2):

package: [thumbs](http://ctan.org/pkg/thumbs)

Changes:

> Option draft (*not*  the default) sets the thumb mark width to 2 pt,
>   thumb mark text colour to black and thumb mark background colour to
>   grey (`gray`). Either do not use this option with the thumbs package at
>   all, or use draft=false, or final, or final=true to get the original
>   appearance of the thumb marks.

`final` option: yes

Answer (score 2):

Package: `changes`

- Option `draft` is the default.

Changes with `final` option:

> The final-option disables markup of changes, only the correct text will be shown. The list of changes is disabled, too.

Answer (score 2):

Package: `flowfram`

Changes:

- Shows the bounding boxes with identifying tags for each frame, the typeblock and the margins.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[draft]{flowfram}

\twocolumntop{static}{1in}

\setstaticcontents{1}{Top Area}

\begin{document}

\marginpar{Marginal Note}\lipsum*[1]

\lipsum*[2-3]\marginpar{Margin Note 2}

\end{document}
```

[image: image of document]

Has `final` option:

[image: image of document in final mode]

Answer (score 1):

Package: `todonotes`

*Note*: there are no changes while using `draft` or `final` *unless changes are made to the `todonotes` package options.*

- option `obeyDraft`: **will** display the to do notes (only output the todos/todolist if in "draft mode")

Changes using `final`:

- option `obeyFinal`: **will not** display the to do notes (suppress output of the todos/todolist if in "final mode")

Answer (score 1):

Package: `pstricks`

While the package pstricks does not support the class option draft, it is possible to add this behaviour:

- All `pspicture` environments will be replaced by white space. PSTricks commands will be ignored.

To do so use LaTeX's internal test for document class options `\@ifclasswith` (c.f. [stackexchange question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110292/testing-for-a-documentclass-option)):

```
\usepackage{pstricks}
\makeatletter
\@ifclasswith{article}{draft}{\PSTricksOff}{}
\makeatother
```

Change the `article` in line 3 to whatever class you have in use.