# Latex generates pdf with black end of line

Tags: boxes

I hope you can help me with this. I am having a "minor" problem with Texmaker. While creating a report some lines contain at the end a "black rectangular character". Initially I thought that was because some blocks of text were copy-pasted from emails and text files, but it also happens when writing the text from scratch.

Here a snippet of the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,draft]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\author{António Domingues}
\begin{document}
\title{Omniviewer \\
Interpret results }
\maketitle
\section*{Scoring}

{\bf Sepscore.out} is the main file of interest. A typical cutoff is p=0 and sepscore better than 0.3.

Example:
\\
\\
\resizebox{14cm}{!} {
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
c1 & c2 & c3 & c4 & c5 & c6 & c7 & c8 & c9 & c10 & c11 & c12 & c13 & c14 \\
\hline 
one & two & three & four & five & six & seven & eight & nine & ten & twelve & thirteen & fourteen & sixteen \\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
}
\\
    Judging from personal comments and the online survey it is fair to say that, as usual, this was a great event from which many benefited. Here are some numbers, taken from the online survey (72 respondents), to substantiate this: 

\begin{itemize}

\item 

Roughly 90\% of participants came from 3 institutes: MPI-CBG (38.9\%), BIOTECH(30.6\%) and  CRTD (23.6\%)  and  the  majority  of  these  were  Predocs  (34.7\%)  or Postdocs (36.1\%). Worthy of note was that a group leader also filled in the survey.

\item 
The talks were considered largely informative or inspiring and 43.5\% of respondents talked to the speakers during the breaks. As for the range of topics/speakers, 43.5\% considered it good and 14.3\% great.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

This is the log file:

```
LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian) (format=pdflatex 2012.5.31) 26 JUN 2012 13:01
entering extended mode
%&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size11.clo
File: size11.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@chapter=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
File: utf8.def 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
Now handling font encoding OML ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OML
Now handling font encoding T1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding T1
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu
File: t1enc.dfu 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
defining Unicode char U+00AB (decimal 171)
defining Unicode char U+00BB (decimal 187)
defining Unicode char U+00BF (decimal 191)
defining Unicode char U+00C0 (decimal 192)
defining Unicode char U+00C1 (decimal 193)
defining Unicode char U+00C2 (decimal 194)
defining Unicode char U+00C3 (decimal 195)
defining Unicode char U+00C4 (decimal 196)
defining Unicode char U+00C5 (decimal 197)
defining Unicode char U+00C6 (decimal 198)
defining Unicode char U+00C7 (decimal 199)
defining Unicode char U+00C8 (decimal 200)
defining Unicode char U+00C9 (decimal 201)
defining Unicode char U+00CA (decimal 202)
defining Unicode char U+00CB (decimal 203)
defining Unicode char U+00CC (decimal 204)
defining Unicode char U+00CD (decimal 205)
defining Unicode char U+00CE (decimal 206)
defining Unicode char U+00CF (decimal 207)
defining Unicode char U+00D0 (decimal 208)
defining Unicode char U+00D1 (decimal 209)
defining Unicode char U+00D2 (decimal 210)
defining Unicode char U+00D3 (decimal 211)
defining Unicode char U+00D4 (decimal 212)
defining Unicode char U+00D5 (decimal 213)
defining Unicode char U+00D6 (decimal 214)
defining Unicode char U+00D8 (decimal 216)
defining Unicode char U+00D9 (decimal 217)
defining Unicode char U+00DA (decimal 218)
defining Unicode char U+00DB (decimal 219)
defining Unicode char U+00DC (decimal 220)
defining Unicode char U+00DD (decimal 221)
defining Unicode char U+00DE (decimal 222)
defining Unicode char U+00DF (decimal 223)
defining Unicode char U+00E0 (decimal 224)
defining Unicode char U+00E1 (decimal 225)
defining Unicode char U+00E2 (decimal 226)
defining Unicode char U+00E3 (decimal 227)
defining Unicode char U+00E4 (decimal 228)
defining Unicode char U+00E5 (decimal 229)
defining Unicode char U+00E6 (decimal 230)
defining Unicode char U+00E7 (decimal 231)
defining Unicode char U+00E8 (decimal 232)
defining Unicode char U+00E9 (decimal 233)
defining Unicode char U+00EA (decimal 234)
defining Unicode char U+00EB (decimal 235)
defining Unicode char U+00EC (decimal 236)
defining Unicode char U+00ED (decimal 237)
defining Unicode char U+00EE (decimal 238)
defining Unicode char U+00EF (decimal 239)
defining Unicode char U+00F0 (decimal 240)
defining Unicode char U+00F1 (decimal 241)
defining Unicode char U+00F2 (decimal 242)
defining Unicode char U+00F3 (decimal 243)
defining Unicode char U+00F4 (decimal 244)
defining Unicode char U+00F5 (decimal 245)
defining Unicode char U+00F6 (decimal 246)
defining Unicode char U+00F8 (decimal 248)
defining Unicode char U+00F9 (decimal 249)
defining Unicode char U+00FA (decimal 250)
defining Unicode char U+00FB (decimal 251)
defining Unicode char U+00FC (decimal 252)
defining Unicode char U+00FD (decimal 253)
defining Unicode char U+00FE (decimal 254)
defining Unicode char U+00FF (decimal 255)
defining Unicode char U+0102 (decimal 258)
defining Unicode char U+0103 (decimal 259)
defining Unicode char U+0104 (decimal 260)
defining Unicode char U+0105 (decimal 261)
defining Unicode char U+0106 (decimal 262)
defining Unicode char U+0107 (decimal 263)
defining Unicode char U+010C (decimal 268)
defining Unicode char U+010D (decimal 269)
defining Unicode char U+010E (decimal 270)
defining Unicode char U+010F (decimal 271)
defining Unicode char U+0110 (decimal 272)
defining Unicode char U+0111 (decimal 273)
defining Unicode char U+0118 (decimal 280)
defining Unicode char U+0119 (decimal 281)
defining Unicode char U+011A (decimal 282)
defining Unicode char U+011B (decimal 283)
defining Unicode char U+011E (decimal 286)
defining Unicode char U+011F (decimal 287)
defining Unicode char U+0130 (decimal 304)
defining Unicode char U+0131 (decimal 305)
defining Unicode char U+0132 (decimal 306)
defining Unicode char U+0133 (decimal 307)
defining Unicode char U+0139 (decimal 313)
defining Unicode char U+013A (decimal 314)
defining Unicode char U+013D (decimal 317)
defining Unicode char U+013E (decimal 318)
defining Unicode char U+0141 (decimal 321)
defining Unicode char U+0142 (decimal 322)
defining Unicode char U+0143 (decimal 323)
defining Unicode char U+0144 (decimal 324)
defining Unicode char U+0147 (decimal 327)
defining Unicode char U+0148 (decimal 328)
defining Unicode char U+014A (decimal 330)
defining Unicode char U+014B (decimal 331)
defining Unicode char U+0150 (decimal 336)
defining Unicode char U+0151 (decimal 337)
defining Unicode char U+0152 (decimal 338)
defining Unicode char U+0153 (decimal 339)
defining Unicode char U+0154 (decimal 340)
defining Unicode char U+0155 (decimal 341)
defining Unicode char U+0158 (decimal 344)
defining Unicode char U+0159 (decimal 345)
defining Unicode char U+015A (decimal 346)
defining Unicode char U+015B (decimal 347)
defining Unicode char U+015E (decimal 350)
defining Unicode char U+015F (decimal 351)
defining Unicode char U+0160 (decimal 352)
defining Unicode char U+0161 (decimal 353)
defining Unicode char U+0162 (decimal 354)
defining Unicode char U+0163 (decimal 355)
defining Unicode char U+0164 (decimal 356)
defining Unicode char U+0165 (decimal 357)
defining Unicode char U+016E (decimal 366)
defining Unicode char U+016F (decimal 367)
defining Unicode char U+0170 (decimal 368)
defining Unicode char U+0171 (decimal 369)
defining Unicode char U+0178 (decimal 376)
defining Unicode char U+0179 (decimal 377)
defining Unicode char U+017A (decimal 378)
defining Unicode char U+017B (decimal 379)
defining Unicode char U+017C (decimal 380)
defining Unicode char U+017D (decimal 381)
defining Unicode char U+017E (decimal 382)
defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)
defining Unicode char U+2013 (decimal 8211)
defining Unicode char U+2014 (decimal 8212)
defining Unicode char U+2018 (decimal 8216)
defining Unicode char U+2019 (decimal 8217)
defining Unicode char U+201A (decimal 8218)
defining Unicode char U+201C (decimal 8220)
defining Unicode char U+201D (decimal 8221)
defining Unicode char U+201E (decimal 8222)
defining Unicode char U+2030 (decimal 8240)
defining Unicode char U+2031 (decimal 8241)
defining Unicode char U+2039 (decimal 8249)
defining Unicode char U+203A (decimal 8250)
defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
)
Now handling font encoding OT1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OT1
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu
File: ot1enc.dfu 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
defining Unicode char U+00B8 (decimal 184)
defining Unicode char U+00BF (decimal 191)
defining Unicode char U+00C5 (decimal 197)
defining Unicode char U+00C6 (decimal 198)
defining Unicode char U+00D8 (decimal 216)
defining Unicode char U+00DF (decimal 223)
defining Unicode char U+00E6 (decimal 230)
defining Unicode char U+00EC (decimal 236)
defining Unicode char U+00ED (decimal 237)
defining Unicode char U+00EE (decimal 238)
defining Unicode char U+00EF (decimal 239)
defining Unicode char U+00F8 (decimal 248)
defining Unicode char U+0131 (decimal 305)
defining Unicode char U+0141 (decimal 321)
defining Unicode char U+0142 (decimal 322)
defining Unicode char U+0152 (decimal 338)
defining Unicode char U+0153 (decimal 339)
defining Unicode char U+2013 (decimal 8211)
defining Unicode char U+2014 (decimal 8212)
defining Unicode char U+2018 (decimal 8216)
defining Unicode char U+2019 (decimal 8217)
defining Unicode char U+201C (decimal 8220)
defining Unicode char U+201D (decimal 8221)
)
Now handling font encoding OMS ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMS
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu
File: omsenc.dfu 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
defining Unicode char U+00A7 (decimal 167)
defining Unicode char U+00B6 (decimal 182)
defining Unicode char U+00B7 (decimal 183)
defining Unicode char U+2020 (decimal 8224)
defining Unicode char U+2021 (decimal 8225)
defining Unicode char U+2022 (decimal 8226)
)
Now handling font encoding OMX ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMX
Now handling font encoding U ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding U
defining Unicode char U+00A9 (decimal 169)
defining Unicode char U+00AA (decimal 170)
defining Unicode char U+00AE (decimal 174)
defining Unicode char U+00BA (decimal 186)
defining Unicode char U+02C6 (decimal 710)
defining Unicode char U+02DC (decimal 732)
defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)
defining Unicode char U+2026 (decimal 8230)
defining Unicode char U+2122 (decimal 8482)
defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2000/07/18 v2.13 AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip43
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0
\@emptytoks=\toks16
\ex@=\dimen103
))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d
\pmbraise@=\dimen104
)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count88
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 211.
\uproot@=\count89
\leftroot@=\count90
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 307.
\classnum@=\count91
\DOTSCASE@=\count92
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 379.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 382.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 467.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box26
\strutbox@=\box27
\big@size=\dimen105
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 567.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 568.
\macc@depth=\count93
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count94
\dotsspace@=\muskip10
\c@parentequation=\count95
\dspbrk@lvl=\count96
\tag@help=\toks17
\row@=\count97
\column@=\count98
\maxfields@=\count99
\andhelp@=\toks18
\eqnshift@=\dimen106
\alignsep@=\dimen107
\tagshift@=\dimen108
\tagwidth@=\dimen109
\totwidth@=\dimen110
\lineht@=\dimen111
\@envbody=\toks19
\multlinegap=\skip44
\multlinetaggap=\skip45
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks20
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2666.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2667.
)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2009/06/22 v3.00 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font) U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 96.
)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2009/06/22 v3.00
)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks21
)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/etc/texmf/tex/latex/config/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2009/08/28 v1.8 graphics configuration of TeX Live
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 91.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2010/03/12 v0.04p Graphics/color for pdfTeX
\Gread@gobject=\count100
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen112
\Gin@req@width=\dimen113
) (./test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 8.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count101
\scratchdimen=\dimen114
\scratchbox=\box28
\nofMPsegments=\count102
\nofMParguments=\count103
\everyMPshowfont=\toks22
\MPscratchCnt=\count104
\MPscratchDim=\dimen115
\MPnumerator=\count105
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks23
)
LaTeX Font Info: Try loading font information for U+msa on input line 11.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2009/06/22 v3.00 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info: Try loading font information for U+msb on input line 11.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2009/06/22 v3.00 AMS symbols B
) [1
{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 16--30
[]
Overfull \hbox (38.36009pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 16--30
[] |
[]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 16--30
[]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 16--30
[]
LaTeX Font Info: Try loading font information for OMS+cmr on input line 36.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/omscmr.fd
File: omscmr.fd 1999/05/25 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info: Font shape `OMS/cmr/m/n' in size <10.95> not available
(Font) Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' tried instead on input line 36.
Overfull \hbox (6.07912pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 37--38
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 Roughly 90% of par-tic-i-pants came from 3 in-sti-tutes: M
PI-CBG (38.9%),|
[]
[1] (./test.aux) )
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
2031 strings out of 495061
23298 string characters out of 1182621
76401 words of memory out of 3000000
5204 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+50000
11045 words of font info for 42 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
28 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
27i,7n,22p,261b,191s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
</usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx
10.pfb></usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></us
r/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/share/texm
f-texlive/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb></usr/share/texmf-texlive/fo
nts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb></usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/type1/pu
blic/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (2 pages, 73742 bytes).
PDF statistics:
33 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35/what-does-overfull-hbox-mean and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49277/what-does-the-draft-mode-change

Comment: RE:@MartinSchroder's comment -- I've been using LaTeX for years and had the same issue.  I've found that Googling my LaTeX solutions is much more constructive than reading through LaTeX manuals, introductory or otherwise, making this my first source of solution.  Please don't post comments just for the sake of being insulting and arrogant.

Comment: This is addressed by [What does “overfull hbox” mean? (Why is there a black mark at the end of a line?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Black rectangle is a sign of overfull. You have to increase a tolerance for example.
https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/%5Coverfullrule

If it doesn't solve your problem you can get better help here: http://tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks to all specially to mnowotka. The 1st link contained the solution: the environment was set to "tolerant" and then all I add to do was adjust the value in the paragraph with \begin{tolerant}{3000}. For the table it was even simpler: all that was needed was to adjust the size in here \resizebox{14cm}.

Comment: This answer is no longer useful; the link is dead.

Answer (score 19):

i just wanted to add that this black box is only created if you have the

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,draft]{report}
                            ^^^^^
```

option set. It will leave if you delete this - and just appear as a warning in `texfile.log`
such as

```
Overfull \hbox (38.36009pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 16--30
Overfull \hbox (6.07912pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 37--38
```

if i remember correctly.

Comment: Quite right epsilon! Deleting "draft" does solve the problem. It was however good to know the source of the problem. Cheers.

Comment: I have black boxes but I'm not using the draft option.