# Highlight underfull boxes

Tags: boxes, microtype, draft, overfull, underfull

Overfull `\hbox`es can be highlighted/marked in the output document by enabling `draft=true` or `overfullrule=true` in the `\documentclass` settings.

Furthermore, slightly overfull or underfull horizontal boxes can often be somewhat reduced by using the [`microtype` package](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/microtype) (since `draft` mode disables microtyping, the `final` option has to be specified for the `microtype` package).

A detailed overview on draft mode [can be found here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49277/what-does-the-draft-mode-change), `microtype` is elaborated [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82001/microtype-settings-for-dummies).

However, is there a way to highlight/mark underfull boxes in the output document?

Comment: with lualatex, lua-visual-debug pakage will colour code shrunk or stretched spaces

Comment: I did not yet switch to lualatex in my production environment. Is there any approach for pdflatex?

Comment: no, only `\showoutput` and look in the log, you can not access the information from within tex

Comment: the `draft` option for the `microtype` package no longer exists, so you do not have to load the package with the `final` option (which doesn't exist anymore, either).