# Black square margin GFX bug

Tags: line-breaking

I've run across a GFX bug that seems to has something to do with text formatting and line breaks. It is a black box the size of a character, that appears in the right margin. It looks like this:

[image: LaTeX GFX bug]
<sub>(source: [it.uu.se](http://user.it.uu.se/~embe8573/LaTeX_GFX_bug.png))</sub>

On my homepage, you can view the entire [document](http://user.it.uu.se/~embe8573/about/degree/x.pdf), as well as the LaTeX [source](http://user.it.uu.se/~embe8573/latex/x.tex). (It is on page 21.)

Comment: You have the `draft` option specified in your `\documentclass` command.  This puts marks in the margin to point out places where TeX has put text outside the margins.  See [What does draft mode change?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49277/2693)

Comment: What is this `GFX`?

Comment: Note: the image is no longer available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using option `parfill` of package `parskip`. That requires a minimum space (`30pt`) at the end of the last line of a paragraph. In your case the paragraph has two lines and the second line is `13.1239pt` too long for the minimum space of `30p`. Therefore TeX prints an overfull `\hbox` warning and because of option `draft` of document class `report` the overfull `\hbox` is marked with a overfull rule with width `5pt`.

Solutions:

- Resolving the overfull `\hbox` warning.
- Removing global option `draft`.
- Smaller minimum space of option `parfill` of package `parskip`:

  ```
  \usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
  \setlength{\parfillskip}{16pt plus 1fil}
  ```

Comment: Thanks, also, @AlanMunn said the same. I removed the `draft` option, and it worked. I browsed the document, and everything seemed OK, so I guess removing that options won't have any other effects except getting rid of that box, which is what I want?