# testing for a documentclass option

Tags: conditionals, class-options

I know that there are lots of similar question, but none of those have helped me so far - and I did google a lot. So my question is: I have a document class (`emulateapj`) which accepts a few options.

In my document, I want to have a conditional test which checks if some option (for example `onecolumn`) is set, and if so, to do a few things like changing font size or line separation.

Something like

```
\IfSubStr{@classoptionslist}{onecolumn}{true}{false}%
```

Just gives me always false.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Is the option defined as a bool?

Answer (score 29):

The kernel provides `\@ifclasswith`:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn]{emulateapj}

\makeatletter
\@ifclasswith{emulateapj}{onecolumn}{\typeout{ONECOLUMN}}{\typeout{NO ONECOLUMN}}
\@ifclasswith{emulateapj}{revtex4}{\typeout{REVTEX4}}{\typeout{NO REVTEX4}}

\makeatother
```

The output on the terminal is

```
ONECOLUMN
NO REVTEX4
```

The `\@ifclasswith` command is only available before `\begin{document}`, so if you want to set up your own conditional you have to do it in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\newif\ifhbonecolumn
\@ifclasswith{emulateapj}{onecolumn}{\hbonecolumntrue}{\hbonecolumnfalse}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\foo}{\ifhbonecolumn fooone\else footwo\fi}
```

Comment: This is only one option if you use no keyval package.

Comment: Great suggestion,`\@ifclasswith`. [clsguide](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/doc/clsguide.pdf) doesn't say anything about it, where is it mentioned?

Comment: @ArchStanton In `source2e.pdf`