# print a different title in the solution of a exam

Tags: exam, latexmk

I created an exam using the `exam` class. I have a small makefile that creates the solutions by adding the `answers` option to the `documentclass`. What I would like to change however, is that the title of the exam changes, if I compile with the `answers` option, such that it says e.g. "Solutions" in red. Is there a simple way (ideally built in the `exam` package) to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Together with the option `answers`, you can use the command `\ifprintanswers`. For example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,addpoints,answers]{exam}

(...)

\begin{document}

\ifprintanswers
    \centerline{\bf Final Exam -- Solutions}
\else
    \centerline{\bf Final Exam}
\fi

\begin{questions}
(...)
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

You can see more details in the exam class documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110292/testing-for-a-documentclass-option):

Before `\begin{document}` these three lines

```
\makeatletter
\@ifclasswith{exam}{answers}{\newcommand{\mytitle}[1]{\textcolor{red}{Solution: #1}}}{\newcommand{\mytitle}[1]{#1}}
\makeatother
```

Create a macro that depends on whether the `answers` option is set or not. At some later point, I can use the macro, e.g.

```
\mytitle{FINAL EXAM}
```

Which prints `FINAL EXAM` if the option is not set, and prints `Solution: FINAL EXAM` in red if the option is set.