# Apply rightside header/footer in \documentclass[oneside]{report}

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, report

If I have `\documentclass[twoside]{report}` and I change it to `\documentclass[oneside]{report}`, `\usepackage{fancyhdr}` automatically prints the left page header and footer. Is there a way to tell fancyhdr/LaTeX to apply the rightside header/footer if `oneside` is used?

... maybe with an if ... else statement?

I tried `\@ifclasswith{report}{oneside}{True}{False}` which yields `You can't use \spacefactor in vertical mode. \@`.

Comment: This looks like a failure to wrap `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` around the if statement.  Does doing that at least get rid of that particular error?  (There;s not enough information to say whether there isn't some other problem.)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with help of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110300/146754) answer.

Add to the preabmle:

```latex
% Check if oneside or twoside
\makeatletter
\@ifclasswith{report}{oneside}{
TRUE
}{
FALSE
}
\makeatother
```

... e.g.

```latex
% Check if oneside or twoside
\makeatletter
\@ifclasswith{report}{oneside}{
\newcommand{\ThesisTitle}{Thesis title text to insert ONESIDE}
}{
\newcommand{\ThesisTitle}{Thesis title text to insert TWOSIDE}
}
\makeatother
```