# How to know if certain parameter is passed to a (standard) class

Tags: options

I'd like to type some text in english or other language depending on an option passed to \documentclass. The idea is to implement a very crude "localization" macro (called \localize, for instance) like:

```
\documentclass[11pt,catalan]{article}
% 'catalan' option is passed automatically to babel if present
\usepackage{babel}
\newcommand{\localize}[2]{(pseudocode) if 'catalan' defined then #1 else #2}
...
\begin{document}
  \localize{Text en català}{English Text}
\end{document}
```

I've been playing with \@classoptionslist, as suggested by [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110292/testing-for-a-documentclass-option/110300), but with no success.

Comment: `\iflanguage{catalan}{Catalan text}{English text}`

Comment: Wow, so simple... Thanks! I suppose it's defined inside Babel