# insert figure in latex

Tags: graphics, eps, draft

I'm using latexian to write my latex file. I need to insert a figure in it. I created a "plots" folder in my Latex folder and my code is as follow:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics{plots/fig1.eps}
 \caption{\label{fig1} Reaction/Diffusion process of Ca$^{2+}$ and IP$_{3}$ metabolism included in the model.}
 \end{figure}
```

A file named `fig1-eps-converted-to.pdf` is created in the "plot" folder automatically. However, the previewed `.pdf` can not show the real figure.

What should I do to show the real figure in my paper?

This is the figure shown in my previed `.pdf`. It's not supposed to be like this:

[image]

My real figure should be like this.

[image]

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The shown figure reveals, that you are most probably using the command `\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}`, so the figure is included in `draft` mode. Remove `[draft]` and it should show up the graphics `.pdf` file

Comment: As well as what @ChristianHupfer suggests, you should remove the extension in your argument to `\includegraphics`: use just `plots/fig1`.

Comment: \documentclass[aps,pre,preprint,groupedaddress,draft,showpacs,showkeys]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
A schematic of our model for the dynamics of intracellular calcium oscillations and intercellular calcium diffusion is shown in Fig.~\ref{fig1}. 

\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics{plots/fig1.eps}
 \caption{\label{fig1} Reaction/Diffusion process of Ca$^{2+}$ and IP$_{3}$ metabolism included in the model. }
 \end{figure}
\bibliography{paper}

\end{document}

Comment: The `draft` option in your document class options is also passed to [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) which causes the output. Remove `draft` from that list.

Comment: Related: [What does the `draft` mode change?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49277/5764)