# journal of materials science template error or epstopdf problem

Tags: epstopdf

I have been having a problem writing an article for the Journal of Materials Science. I am using their template and when it comes to figures I get the following result in the text.
[image: example]

I am using the following preamble:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,draft]{svjour3}
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
```

and the figure insertion with the following:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure3a.eps}
    \caption{example}
    \label{fig:4}
\end{figure}
```

I am not getting any errors and the converted pdf file looks ok but nothing displays in the text except from what you see in the figure. Can anyone help me with this? Has anyone stumbled on this problem before?

Cheers

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Remove the `draft` option or type `\usepackage[final]{graphicx}`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49277/what-does-the-draft-mode-change

Comment: amazing! thank you very much for the help! that indeed was the problem and I also apologize for not noticing the other question! I thought this was a problem due to the template initially! How do I accept the answer or mark the question as solved?

Comment: Don't worry: I *knew* there was a similar question. Just wait that the question is closed as duplicate. Be again welcome and don't be afraid to ask more questions!