# Split thesis chapters into separate files for compilation speed

Tags: input, include, thesis, subfiles

I am writing a thesis using a template similar to [this template](https://github.com/suchow/Dissertate). The main file (dissertation.tex) uses `\include{}` to include each chapter. I have a large chapter (over 60 pages with 70 images) that takes over thirty seconds to compile and view. I want to split this chapter into two files, chapter4part1 and chapter4part2, so that I can compile and view just the part I am working on.

I have tried using `\includeonly{}`, `\input{}` and the [`subfiles`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfiles?lang=en) package but have not been able to compile and view quicker than the original. Is there a way to structure my files and commands to quickly compile and view just chapter4part1?

Edit: clarified question to state I want to split one chapter into two files.

Comment: If it takes so long because you use `TiKZ` figures which are everytime compiled, try `external` tikzlibrary to just compile them when needed. Another solution could be to use `standalone`.

Comment: I think everyone has missed the point of my question. I want to split a chapter into two .tex files without a large compilation speed penalty.

Comment: Create a `chapter4.tex` which contains `\chapter{Name of chapter} \input{chapter4part1} \input{chapter4part2}` and comment or no one of these `\input` according what you want to see.

Comment: @Ignasi I have tried this but have suffered a large increase in the compilation time, even with all the answers provided to this question and others. Is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention what kind of thesis you have, pictures and so on, so I'm just going to go with what I got. I'd put the two parts in environments and `\excludecomment` them using the `comment` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{partone}{}{}
\newenvironment{parttwo}{}{}

\usepackage{comment}
%\excludecomment{partone}
\excludecomment{parttwo}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mychapter.tex}
\begin{partone}
Part one of your thesis
\end{partone}
\begin{parttwo}
Part two
\end{parttwo}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
Tableofcontents
\input mychapter.tex
Chapter 2,3,4,5

\end{document}
```

For completeness, I will also include something to externalize images (as mentioned in comments to the question). The image below doesn't mean anything. I just wanted to use something with at least some compilation time. You will need to run `pdflatex` (or whatever engine you require for your thesis) with the shell escape option to make use of this method.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{65}{155}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [scale=5,
        tdplot_main_coords,
        axis/.style={->,black,very thin},
        vector/.style={-stealth,black,thick },
        curve/.style={black,thin}]
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (1.2,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,1.2,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1.2) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
    \draw[axis,dashed] (0,0,0) -- (-1.2,0,0) node[anchor=south west]{};
    \draw[axis,dashed] (0,0,0) -- (0,-1.2,0) node[anchor=south east]{};
    \tdplotsinandcos{\sintheta}{\costheta}{45}
    \draw[vector,green!80!black] (0,0,0) -- (.62*\costheta,.62*\sintheta,0) node[above=.27in,right=.03in] {\Large $\rho$};
    \tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{0}
    \tdplotdrawarc[curve,tdplot_rotated_coords,thick,magenta!80,<-]{(O)}{1}{0}{90}{}{}
    \node[magenta!80] at (.8,0,.8) {\Large$\phi$};
    \foreach \angle in {0,30,...,180}
    {
        \tdplotsinandcos{\sintheta}{\costheta}{\angle}%
        \coordinate (P) at (0,0,.62*\sintheta);
        \tdplotdrawarc[curve,very thin]{(P)}{.62*\costheta}{0}{180}{}{}
    }
    \tdplotsinandcos{\sintheta}{\costheta}{180}
    \tdplotdrawarc[curve,thick,cyan!80,->]{(P)}{.8*\costheta}{-90}{260}{}{}
    \node[cyan!80] at (.7,.7,0) {\Large$\theta$};
    \foreach \angle in {0,30,...,360}
    {
        \tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{\angle}
        \tdplotdrawarc[curve,tdplot_rotated_coords,very thin]{(O)}{.62}{0}{90}{}{}
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I use images with various extensions, .jpg, .eps and .pdf.

Comment: @MowingBar Assuming you're using package `graphicx` to include images, you could use the `demo` option for faster compilation: `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}`.

Comment: Or, if your class file already loads the package: `\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}`.

Answer (score 0):

did you have a look at http://www.howtotex.com/tag/faster-latex/

I think you already tried everything from "Part I", so you should look at "Part IV".

I guess that the compile speed depends a lot on the included packages. By compiling parts of the document you also include the all your needed packages. So making them `static` could improve the compile speed of your documents.

EDIT: If it's ok for you, you could also use `draftmode` - `\documentclass[draft]` to get rid of the pictures.
see: [What does the draft mode change?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49277/what-does-the-draft-mode-change)

Comment: I want to split a chapter into two separate files.