# Vector graphic eps works for documentclass article, not for book

Tags: graphics, eps, class-options, draft

When I use this example from [here](https://embedded.eecs.berkeley.edu/concurrency/latex/latexWithEPS.html),  I can simply include the given `figure.eps` with the documentclass `\documentclass[10pt]{article}`

The provided `*.eps` file is displayed properly. As soon as I change the document class to  `\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,draft]{book}`

(remove the `\abstract` section, since available in articles only) I get this screen and the picture is not displayed in my `*.pdf`
[image]

Why is the `*.eps` not displayed?

Comment: it is because of the `draft` option. Using this option makes the compiling to be shorter. A reason for this quicker compilation is that pictures are not displayed. Instead, a blank frame (having same dimensions) with their name is printed.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is unrelated to the change of class, you have added `draft`, the main effect of which is to stop the loading of images.

Answer (score 3):

When you load a class, you can pass global options to it as following: `\documentclass[<global-options>]{<class-name>}`. These options impact then the whole document, e.g., paper size (`a4paper`), main font size (`10pt`).

One of them is the `draft` option. It is used when you want to compile a draft version of your document. In exchange of a shorter compiling time, [it inhibits/simplifies some features](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49277/64454) that are not essential.

In the case of the `graphicx` package, all pictures embedded with the `\includegraphics` macro are replaced by a blank frame with picture filename (i.e. the effect you observed).

**TL;DR** to see the picture, remove the `draft` option passed to `\documentclass`.