# What would be the most efficient way to insert image in a document?

Tags: graphics, crop, includegraphics, performance

In terms of occupied space and performance (compiling time), what would be the most efficient way to insert image in a document :

- Insert images from different files (multiple .jpg, .png, etc.);
- Insert images from a single big file (only 1 .jpg or .png for exemple), that you need to crop every time you use `\includegraphics`;
- Any other way (?).

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! 1.compiling time: you could use the [draft mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49277/124842) 2. From my point of view the cropping part isen't latex related.(or could you specify your question?). You are welcome.

Comment: I personally don't think cropping every image is a good practice. Also, if you need to modify the source image you will have to modify (+load/save) a potentially huge file.

Comment: How exactly is one supposed to separate multiple images in one jpg?  One can separate multiple images (pages) in a PDF using \includegraphics[page=...]

Comment: Concerning the resulting file size it probably won't make much difference. If you use a single big image and include it multiple times, it will only be embedded once in the pdf - on the other hand will the file size of the image containing all the elements be larger. My guess is that both effects will probably cancel each other out and it boils down to the additional work to crop the image each time - so probably not worth the effort.