# Black symbols in the \listoffigures \listoftables

Tags: table-of-contents, errors, hyphenation

I want to add a `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` at the end of the document. Whole document was created with latexmk under Linux. So far so good, no errors by creating the document. By inserting `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` in the document, I get some strange behaviour with black symbols at the page, see
[image: Black symbols listoffigures]

[image: Black symbols listoftables]

I know this behaviour from the document with black symbols at the end of a sentence, when the hyphenation doesn't work correct and the word "is to long" for the line. Then I have to correct it and all is fine.

The expected hyphentation in picture [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uCz7.png) like is `Lig-ges-me-yer`.
I put here the code from the relevant chapter for the table. The relevant part is the caption. By using the command `\citeauthor`, the hyphentation seems not work...

```
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{ | p{0.36\textwidth} | p{0.18\textwidth} | } 
\hline 
Eingabebereich: & 1 $ \leq \ $ Wert $\leq$ 99 \\
Gültige Äquivalenzklasse: & 1 $ \leq \ $ Wert $\leq$ 99 \\ 
Ungültige Äquivalenzklasse: & Wert $ \leq $ 1 \\ 
Ungültige Äquivalenzklasse: & Wert $ \geq $ 99 \\ \hline
\end{tabular} 
\caption{Beispiel zur Aufteilung in entsprechende Äquivalenzklassen (vgl. \protect\citeauthor{Liggesmeyer2009}, 2009).}
\label{tab:Äquivalenzklassen}
\end{table}
```

Thank you for all hints!

Question: How can i change this behaviour here? Thanks for hints!

Complete example:

```
\begin{document}

 \begin{table}[!htbp]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{tabular}{ | p{0.36\textwidth} | p{0.18\textwidth} | } 
    \hline 
    Eingabebereich: & 1 $ \leq \ $ Wert $\leq$ 99 \\
    Gültige Äquivalenzklasse: & 1 $ \leq \ $ Wert $\leq$ 99 \\ 
    Ungültige Äquivalenzklasse: & Wert $ \leq $ 1 \\ 
    Ungültige Äquivalenzklasse: & Wert $ \geq $ 99 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular} 
    \caption{Beispiel zur Aufteilung in entsprechende Äquivalenzklassen (vgl. \protect\citeauthor{Liggesmeyer2009}, 2009).}
    \label{tab:Äquivalenzklassen}
    \end{table}

\clearpage
\listoffigures
\clearpage

\clearpage
\listoftables
\par 

\clearpage
\lstlistoflistings

\clearpage
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{misc/literatur}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems the effect of document class option `draft`. Guess you can find "overfull \hbox" in `\listofXXX` in log file. If your document is at final state, you can remove `draft` option from document class. Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49278/79060.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! For the first errors should work!
For the second, see picture two not! The hyphenation from the author "Liggesmeyer" is wrong. In the code, it's a \citeauthor command...

Comment: What's the expected hyphenation? And can you try to provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to reproduce that problem?

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ: Thanks for the hint! I added in my question the relevant code! If you need more code arround them, I can make a MWE wich includes the generation of the table and the listoffigures. Let me know! Thank you!

Comment: Yes I think a complete example would be helpful.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Should work now as added above!

Comment: Perhaps LaTeX doesn't know how to hyphenate "Liggesmeyer". Try adding "\hyphenation{Lig-ges-me-yer}" before `\begin{document}` and recompile.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ: I have done it. Doesn't works...

Comment: Can you make your example a truly complete one? It should begins with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`, so others can reproduce your problem by copy-paste and compile. You also need to provide the content of or link to the item of "Liggesmeyer2009" and bib style `apacite`.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ: OK. That's hard to extract all the stuff outside the whole work (about 500 lines of codes and a huge of documents like the bib file, the main document, the chapter,... I will replace "Liggesmeyer2009" with Liggesmeyer and the year. No link, but works from the hyphenation mode!
Thank you!