# Includegraphics fails silently, why?

Tags: graphics

I have a graphic in .png, .jpg and .pdf format. When I use graphicx, instead of rendering the figure I get a box with the file name in it. The log, which is posted, doesn't show any problem finding the file.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,draft]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\author{Anna Naden}
\title{Doc title}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{temp.jpg}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The image I am trying to embed:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JOi2.jpg

The log file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wc4ibq9g0Sq0pBOFvoGhkc5yvlp7Q917/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That's the `draft` option. Remove it if you want to see the images. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49277/35864 for a collection of effects a global `draft` option may have.

Comment: Do you prefer \includegraphics to fail screaming loudly ;-)?

Comment: @Bernard Presumably, yes, especially when it is a very nice image :)