# Draft mode in ConTeXt

Tags: context-mkiv, draft

Is there the draft mode in ConTeXt (to highlight overfull/underfull boxes and stuff)? If not, how can I re-create its features?

I've searched through [ConTeXt wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net) and all I found is `--draft` commandline option which doesn't seem suitable for ConTeXt Mark IV.

Comment: Does `\overfullrule 5pt\relax` do what you want?

Comment: @Aditya: for overfull boxes - pretty much) But what about underfull ones? In the wake of your answer I've found [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/underfullrule). Does this have to be some [large extra routine](https://gist.github.com/wspr/0f42f19422d446490e0e) too?

Comment: LaTeX doesn't show underful boxes either :-). I don't know TeX internals well enough to understand the link that you posted. So I don't know how to translate it to ConTeXt

Comment: @Aditya: well, neither do I) thanks for your help... again ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a new feature in ConTeXt to show overfull and *underfull* boxes!

```
\enabletrackers[visualizers.justification] % overfull/underfull
\enabletrackers[typesetters.suspects] % suspicious spacing


\setuppapersize[A8]
\setuplayout[width=3mm] \showframe

\starttext

\hsize 3mm

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxx
x

$x$x

x:$x$

\stoptext
```

With just the `visualizers.justification`, you get:

[image]

With just `typesetters.suspects`, you get:

[image]

And with both, you get:

[image]

Comment: that's pretty neat! and I guess that solves the problem... but it gives a lot of false positives (perhaps caused by hanging punctuation)... is there a way to set some visibility threshold?)

Comment: Not sure. You can ask on the [mailing list](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.context/93724) where this was announced